# Show if $0 \le a <b$ implies $0 \le a^{\frac{1}{n}}<b^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: induction, exponentiation, problem-solving

Given that $0\le a<b$ show that $0\leq a^{1/n}<b^{1/n}$

Is this proof by induction?

Show it's correct for $n=1$

Assume true for $n=k$, then $0\leq a^{1/k}<b^{1/k}$ holds for some $k$,

Show that this holds for $0\leq a^{1/{k+1}}<b^{1/{k+1}}$ , but I can't get it to show this.

Comment: Do you know that $a<b\iff a^n<b^n$? This is a little easier to show by induction and easily gives the result.

Comment: This was part 1 of the question. I completed that

Comment: Set $a\mapsto a^{1/n},b\mapsto b^{1/n}$ to get $a^{1/n}<b^{1/n}\iff (a^{1/n})^n<(b^{1/n})^n$. Do you see how to finish?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show that if $a,b \ge 0$ then $b \le a$ implies $b^n \le a^n$?

Its contrapositive is the statement $a^n < b^n$ implies $a < b$.

Comment: This is a useful answer, for it suggests the approach of showing something that is easier to show using induction and basic order properties of $\mathbb R$, which then turns out to be equivalent to the desired result.  Also,  user43249 has since commented that they did prove that in the first part of the problem, so in context it is even more useful.

Answer (score 0):

$x\mapsto x^{1/n}$ is increasing, therefore the claim follow.

Comment: This is a restatement of the problem, not an approach to proving it.